# Exception thrown: 'System.FM' reported Error for property 'State'

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm attempting to launch a Service Fabric cluster in Azure, but the system services are failing to start, throwing an exception as follows:

> 'System.FM' reported Error for property 'State'.
> Partition is below target replica or instance count.
> EventStoreService 5 3 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000009000
> N/P InBuild _Type191_3 133293166059699311

I'm running Service Fabric version 9.1.1799.9590 on a 5 node-count cluster using the Windows-2022-Datacenter image.

Attached are some additional screenshots of the errors received via the Service Fabric Explorer.

[image: Health evaluation depicting the error]
[image: Additional error when trying to access service details]

I've tried to reinstall the cluster, but I am continuing to see the error. Does anyone have a suggestion on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: You mentioned reinstalling the cluster - do you have any non-default cluster settings or policies in place (e.g. placement constraints) that might be preventing the system services from creating their additional replicas? How many nodes show up in the cluster per SFX?